# How to make multiple queries to populate recyclerview in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve some data from firebase database and populate it to recyclerview. The logic behind the query is to display users with opposite sex as the current user but the same hall. Example if the current user is a "boy" and is in "Legon" hall, populate recyclerview with "females" in legon hall from database.

Users Database:
[image]

This is what I am trying to do but is not working

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    final String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    final User user = new User();

    final String halls = user.getHalls();


    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)

        {

            if(dataSnapshot.child("Male").hasChild(user_id)){


                query = databaseReference.child("Female").orderByChild("halls").equalTo(halls);
            }
            else{

                query = databaseReference.child("Male").orderByChild("halls").equalTo(halls);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public  void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
    });

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewholder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewholder>(
        User.class,
        R.layout.users_row,
        UserViewholder.class,
        query

        ) {
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(UserViewholder viewHolder, User model, int position) {
        viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
        viewHolder.setLevels(model.getLevels());
        viewHolder.setDownloadUrl(getApplicationContext(), model.getDownloadUrl());
        }

        };

        users2.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong in here

```
final User user = new User();
final String halls = user.getHalls();
```

because `halls` always return null

You should change it to

```
User user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
final String halls = user.getHalls();
```

Comment: Please the "user" is just the class i created containing some info not..It is not the "firebaseUser" @Phan Van Linh